# Error: A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, redistributable

When I try to run the VS 2010 redistributable "vcredist_x86.exe", an error "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine" occurs and blocks me from installation.

I have actually installed VS 2010 pro on my computer. But I actually have no idea what an VS 2010 redistributable means and why the error occurred. Can anyone help to explain or solve the problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You cannot overwrite a new version of the DLLs with an old one.  That would be bad.  Never run vcredist on your dev machine, only on the machine on which you want to deploy your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redistributable packages are only required on machines that don't have VS2010 installed to provide the required runtimes. If you check the Microsoft download page for example:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5555

The opening paragraph is:

The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2010 installed.

You should only need to install the redistributable on machines that you deploy your application to. The newer version is probably that Windows Update has updated to a later version than is currently downloadable in the standalone version, but in general it shouldn't pose you any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot PeterJ. Can you also explain what exactly is "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine". Is it because I have already installed VC++ 2010 and the distributable embedded in the VC++ 2010 is newer than independent Redistributable packages? Thanks!

Comment: Just thought to add that part at the same time you were typing. It's pretty common when you download the redistributable that a Windows update will be available straight away on it.